# Audio loop doesn't stop...How to destroy a loop?

Tags: android, audio, android-mediaplayer

Here is code that I use to create a loop-all and stop button.  However, I have a bug.  If you tap the loop-all button it plays fine, and when you hit the stop button, it stops the audio.  But when I tap the loop-all button, the audio plays as usual, but when I step out of the program (i.e., hit the back button) and come back in, the stop button doesn't stop the audio.  To stop it, I had to go to task manager and end the program.  It is the only way to stop it in that situation.  How can I fix this?  Anyone have any ideas?  Any help would be appreciated.

```
public class OneGrammar extends ActionBarActivity {

private ListView lv;
private MediaPlayer mp;
private MediaPlayer mp2;
int[] myAudio = {R.raw.g_1100, R.raw.g_1101, R.raw.g_1102, R.raw.g_1103, R.raw.g_1104, R.raw.g_1105,
        R.raw.g_1106, R.raw.g_1107, R.raw.g_1108, R.raw.g_1109, R.raw.g_1110, R.raw.g_1111, R.raw.g_1112, 
        R.raw.g_1113, R.raw.g_1114, R.raw.g_1115};
int mCompleted = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.one_grm);

    Button btnLoop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    Button btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (mp2 != null) {

                if (mp2.isPlaying()) {
                    mp2.stop();

                }
                mp2.reset();
                mp2.release();
                mp2 = null;
            }
            }
    });

    btnLoop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {



        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            mp2 = MediaPlayer.create(getBaseContext(), myAudio[0]);
            mp2.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp2)
                {
                    mCompleted++;
                    mp2.reset();
                    if (mCompleted < myAudio.length) 
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(myAudio[mCompleted]);
                            if (afd != null) 
                            {
                                mp2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                afd.close();
                                mp2.prepare();
                                mp2.start();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) 
                        {
                           ex.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    } 
                    else if (mCompleted == myAudio.length) 
                    {
                        mCompleted =0;
                        try
                        {
                            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getResources().openRawResourceFd(myAudio[mCompleted]);
                            if (afd != null) 
                            {
                                mp2.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
                                afd.close();
                                mp2.prepare();
                                mp2.start();
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex) 
                        {
                           ex.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        mCompleted=0;
                         mp2.release();
                         mp2 = null;
                    }

                }
            });


            mp2.start();  

        }

    });
```